# counting sequences over A,B,C with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

How many sequences of length $20$ over the alphabet $\{A,B,C\}$ satisfies the following constraints:

(1) There are 8 A's , 7 B's and 5 C's.

(2) The sub-sequences CC, BA and AB do not appear.

If it were not for condition (1), we could solve this by recurrence.

Comment: Can you post the solution for recurrence with no condition 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

First let us place the $5$ letters $C$ according to the condition that $CC$ is not allowed.

- Find the number of suitable arrangements that start with letter $C$ and end with letter $C$.
- Find the number of suitable arrangements that start with letter $C$ and do not end with letter $C$.
- Find the number of suitable arrangementsthat do not start with letter $C$ and end with letter $C$.
- Find the number of suitable arrangementsthat do not start with letter $C$ and do not end with letter $C$.

Under first bullet there are $4$ non-empty subwords only using letter $A$ or only using letter $B$.

Under second and third bullet there are $5$ non-empty subwords only using letter $A$ or only using letter $B$.

Under last bullet there are $6$ non-empty subwords only using letter $A$ or only using letter $B$.